# Flask, Celery, Pytest, and apply_async countdown confusion

Tags: flask, celery, pytest

I'm sure this is noted somewhere, but I'm spinning my wheels, so hopefully someone on here can help.

I'm working with a Flask app that uses Celery and I'm testing with Pytest. Here are the two tests:

```
def test_celery_tasks_countdown_apply_async(celery_app, celery_worker):
    r1 = add.apply_async((4, 4), countdown=2)
    r2 = multiply.apply_async((4, 4), countdown=2)
    assert r1.get(timeout=10) == 8
    assert r2.get(timeout=10) == 16

def test_celery_tasks_countdown_signatures(celery_app, celery_worker):
    r1 = add.s(4, 4).apply_async(countdown=2)
    r2 = multiply.s(4, 4).apply_async(countdown=2)
    assert r1.get(timeout=10) == 8
    assert r2.get(timeout=10) == 16
```

The actual tasks are like so:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@shared_task()
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
```

These pass if I run them one by one.

```
pytest tests/test_tasks.py::test_celery_tasks_countdown_apply_async
pytest tests/test_tasks.py::test_celery_tasks_countdown_signatures
```

But if I run them together (by calling the whole `test_tasks.py` file), they both fail.

```
pytest tests/test_tasks.py
```

I've got some other tests (eg, for `delay`) that work. And if I remove the `countdown` option from these, they both pass if run together.

Why does using the `countdown` option and running these tests together cause failure?

Right now, my fixture in `conftest.py` look like this:

```
pytest_plugins = ('celery.contrib.pytest', )

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:8001',
        'result_backend': 'redis://localhost:8001',
        'task_always_eager': False,
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm leaving this question up as I believe it's a valid question that needs some documentation. While I still do not understand the issue or know how to resolve it within the confines of my automated tests, I have succeeded in getting my to run tasks locally outside of PyTest.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but more of a workaround to get the results to save to the backend and tests to complete. But the actual tasks aren't sent to the queue and the countdown option seems to be ignored, both of which aren't what I'm looking for.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:8001',
        'result_backend': 'redis://localhost:8001',
        'task_always_eager': True,
        'task_ignore_result': False,
        'task_store_eager_result': True,
    }
```

Reference [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=broker_heartbeat#task-always-eager).

I'm not sure I want to use these in production, so this is just making my tests pass. I still would love to know why this is all happening.